# Python keyboard lib returns upper and lower cases on Windows but only lower cases on Linux

Tags: python, linux, keyboard, debian, keyboard-events

I used the [keyboard](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard) python library to get keyboard inputs into my application and I found a strange irregularity. When testing on Windows, the print result shows capital or lower case letters based on whether or not I'm holding down the shift key. However when testing on Debian linux, it seems to only report lower cases regardless if I am holding down shift or not. As the matter of fact this also affects punctuation symbols, special characters and brackets. Shift 5 still shows up as 5 Is this something that's unavoidable or is there something I'm missing?

I'd like the library to provide me with capitals and special characters on linux, like it does on windows, because otherwise I'm gonna have to do my own lookup table to conversion.

```
import keyboard

while True:
    event = keyboard.read_event()
    if event.event_type == keyboard.KEY_DOWN:
        print(dir(event))
        print('key pressed', event.name)
```

Comment: Just so I can understand this better-you want to stop the key being pressed from being uppercase or lowercase depending on the shift key and always make it lowercase?

Comment: I do. I'd like to receive the capitals and special characters, but when I run the app on linux, the events I are always lower case despite me holding the shift key.  it doesn't seem to be the case on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I still don't understand which you want to do (make keys uppercase or lowercase), so here's an example of both.

Lowercase ALWAYS:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Listener

def on_press(key):
    try:
        print(key.char)
    except:
        print(key)

with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

And for always uppercase:

```
import keyboard

hotkeys = []
nums = {1: '!', 2: '@', 3: '#', 4: '$', 5: '%', 6: '^', 7: '&', 8: '*', 9: '(', 10: ')'}
letters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

for letter in letters:
    hotkeys.append(letter)

for num in range(10):
    hotkeys.append(str(num))

while True:
    for hotkey in hotkeys:
        if keyboard.is_pressed(f'shift+{hotkey}'):
            try:
                hotkey = int(hotkey)
                print(nums[hotkey])
            except:
                hotkey = hotkey.upper()
                print(hotkey)

            while True:
                if not keyboard.is_pressed(f'shift+{hotkey}'):
                    break

        elif keyboard.is_pressed(hotkey):
            print(hotkey)
            while True:
                if not keyboard.is_pressed(hotkey):
                    break
```

The lowercase code works by using `pynput`, which gives lowercase letters no matter what, and is arguably a better python library than `keyboard`.

The uppercase code is a little more complicated. I made a list of some hotkeys that are possible, like 'shift+5' is '%', then I go into a while True loop and wait for a key to be pressed. First we check if the user also pressed shift, and if they didn't press shift, then we just print the hotkey in the lowercase version. This code obviously doesn't cover every character (like '|'), but it does cover the most used ones. You could add more to your liking.

Also note that I added a while loop so keyboard input isn't echoed (detects multiple times after only one key stroke), so you must release the key before the next iteration of the loop starts.

Comment: Ok so it seems that you've provided the exact thing I thought I wouldn't have to do - which is make a lookup table, check if the shift key is pressed and use the table's character instead of the provided character.

On Windows, I don't have to do any lookup tables. if I press Shift + g, I will receive an event containing G and if it's Shft P 4, it will be $ symbol. But on linux it seems like you have to program your own solution to getting capitals and special characters. That's fine and I would have done so myself, I just figured there was a way to configure something to do it automatically

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience @user2175010, I also would not like to use the lookup table, but it seems that the only other way to really do this is to make your own module or something similar.

Comment: This may very well be because WIndows handles all the modifier keys automatically for you while on linux you have to do so yourself. Because this is the third route I've taken (first being evdev library, then keyboard and now pyinput) that seems to be incapable to discerning between capitals/special characters and lower cases. and the programmer has to do the conversion themselves. That's really all I needed to figure out.

Comment: Yeah that's fine, if I gotta do it myself, then I'll do it myself, no problem, I just wanted to make sure that I'm not about to re-invent the wheel here. Maybe there was something that I was missing. It's all good.

Comment: Also why is pyinput better than keyboard?

Comment: `Pynput` uses a thread, that allows both controlling and detecting the mouse and keyboard, which makes it easier to detect key presses than `keyboard`, since you don't have to use while True loops, or bind hotkeys. In addition, pynput is cross platform, which is good for some people who don't have root on Linux, and can't install/use `keyboard` because of this.

Comment: To your earlier comment, yeah it probably isn't too bad, since there aren't too many keys on the keyboard. You'll notice I used while loops instead of manually adding, and lists instead of dictionaries (for all the the hotkeys), so really it only takes a few lines of code.